# Virtual Key Media Stop not working in Windows 11 - VK_MEDIA_STOP (0xB2) Python

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

```
import win32api

win32api.keybd_event(0xB2, 0)
```

This code will successfully stop any media playing whether its chrome or windows media player etc on Windows 10 but after updating to Windows 11 it no longer works. I have tried on 3 different Windows 11 computers and I get the same problem. If I change the virtual key to something else from the microsoft list of virtual keys (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) like VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE    **0xB3**    Play/Pause Media key it works in Windows 11.

Did microsoft change something for this feature in windows 11?

Answer (score 2):

the stop media key does not seem to be supported on windows 11 at this moment. even the one on my keyboard does not work anymore. the stop button is also missing from te media player. seeing as windows 11 is still in its early stages it might get reimplemented so only time will tell.